# C# Query Select first since value changed

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a database table that looks like this:

[image: Database]

Now. This is a Status History indicator for **DetectorID** 1541.

I only want to show 1 row at my website. To do this i excecute the following query.

```
[Query]
public IQueryable<ScannerStatusHistory> GetScannerStatusHistoryy(int detectorID)
{
    return ObjectContext.ScannerStatusHistories.Where(t => t.DetectorID == detectorID).OrderByDescending(d => d.TimeStamp).Take(1); ;
}
```

So what it does, it grabs the newest row (**Based on TimeStamp**), and shows it.

This will give me the results of `ScannerStatusHistoryID 61`.

But, what i would like to have, is the row of the last time a value got changed.

As you can see on `ScannerStatusHistoryID 54`, `RC3` had a value of `4`.  Then on `ScannerStatusHistoryID 57`, it changed back to `3`.

Since then, the values did not change.
What i would like to have then, is the query to grab the `ScannerStatusHistoryID 57`.  Untill the value changes again, then i want it to grab the first of that one.

How do i achieve this? i was thinking about counting the results where it matched the last query. However, in this example, it will return 7 results (Since the first 4 are the same as the last 3). And so it wont give you the right result.

Comment: do you want control value of all `hwd` and `RC` columns? or `RC3` enough for you?

Comment: Basically, what i get now is the latest result. However, i don't need to know that, but would like to know since when it was changed.

Comment: Since 2012 sql sever has LEAD , LAG which gives the simplest solition to the problem. Is usind sql directly an option? Linq as in .Net 4.6.1 do not support  analytic functions of sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your query like this to achive it:

```
//return ObjectContext.ScannerStatusHistories.Where(t => t.DetectorID == detectorID).OrderByDescending(d => d.TimeStamp).Take(1);
    var lastRow = ObjectContext.ScannerStatusHistories.Where(t => t.DetectorID == detectorID).OrderByDescending(d => d.TimeStamp).FirstOrDefault();
//Get last changed row
    if (lastRow != null)
    {
        var lastChangeRow = ObjectContext.ScannerStatusHistories
        .Where(t => t.DetectorID == detectorID
                && (t.HBD1 != lastRow.HBD1 || t.HBD2 != lastRow.HBD2 || t.HWD1 != lastRow.HWD1 || t.HWD2 != lastRow.HWD2 || t.RC1 != lastRow.RC1 || t.RC2 != lastRow.RC2 || t.RC3 != lastRow.RC3 || t.RC4 != lastRow.RC4))
            .OrderByDescending(d => d.TimeStamp)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    //Return next row
        if (lastChangeRow != null)
        {
            return ObjectContext.ScannerStatusHistories
            .Where(x => lastChangeRow.TimeStamp < x.TimeStamp
                && x.DetectorID == detectorID)
            .OrderBy(d => d.TimeStamp)
            .Take(1);
        }
    }
return ObjectContext.ScannerStatusHistories.Where(t => t.DetectorID == detectorID).OrderBy(d => d.TimeStamp).Take(1);
```

But maby it's better just **not add row if nothing is changed**?

Comment: We can't do that (If nothing is changed). The system gives an update every x minutes in this example. However, i will try you're solution.

Comment: @Mitch you always can put a trigger on insert in MS SQL where you can check if everything is the same.

Comment: That is true Teo. However, this is a History table. We want to get every data the system sends. If we only send the data when it changes. We don't know if the system is running the other x days.

Comment: @Mitch ok another way to solve it is to add [calculated column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) to your table `LastChangeTimeStamp` and put all compare logic there. Maby it will be a bit cleanier. Moreover if your table is a really bit you always can put an index on that column.

Comment: I want to change nothing unless it is really necessary. I see what you are doing with the query, however it does not recognize anything from the var lastRow.

Comment: @Mitch what do you mean - doesn't recognize?

Comment: When i type for example **lastRow.** it does not show me anything like DetectorID or TimeStamp etc. In place of that, i get options like: ElementAt, Distinct etc.

Comment: @Mitch since you need 1 row use `.FirstOrDefault()` instead of `Take(1)`

Comment: It's working now. At the bottom you have this line: **&& t.DetectorID == detectorID** I changed the **t** to **x**. I'm getting the right results now. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have 1 more question. When the status of the system was the same since the beginning. The Query keeps searching for a difference that is not there. And so it will give me a error. Is there a way to solve this problem @teo van kot

Comment: @Mitch just check lastChangeRow on null. If yes - return lasr row

Comment: did it. I already did it, but then it was showing me the newest value. All i had to do was change **OrderByDescending** to **OrderBy**. Did not think clearly yesterday...

Comment: @Mitch you can edit my answer to right answer and i accept it, if you whould like